# Configuration BjyAuthorize and ZfcUser to work as administrator and a normal user

Tags: configuration, module, zend-framework2

I have installed both of the modules in my skeleton application. both are working with the configuration examples they have given here https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize.

I have also installed ZfcAdmin and added some functionalists to it. I need to block it for not less than admin role. have created roles in db guest, user admin

the user I have created has admin role and here is part of my configuration file of BjyAuthorize module

```
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
                array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest','user')),
                array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'stuff', 'roles' => array('user')),
                array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array()),
                // Below is the default index action used by the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)
                array('controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user')),
                array('controller' => 'ZfcAdmin\Controller\Admin', 'roles' => array('admin')),
            ),
```

I have added the controller 'ZfcAdmin\Controller\Admin' with the role admin but it still blocks the admin section.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it was just a miss understanding, here controllers are the in-vocable keys we have defined in module for controllers and for 'ZfcAdmin\Controller\Admin' it is 'ZfcAdmin\Controller\AdminController'.so it worked ...